# How to get value with variable id in jquery?

Tags: jquery, django-templates

```js
function addDictToCookie(id) {
    var name = $("#" + id + "input[id = material_name]").val();
    var unit = $("#" + id + "select[id = material_unit] :selected").text();
    var count = $("#" + id + "input[id = material_count]").val();
    var dict = { "name": name, "unit": unit, "count": count }
    Cookies.set('new', dict, { expires: 0.001 })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="GET" id="{{material.Id}}">
    <div class="col-sm-5 topbox_insidebox_insideblocks">
        <input type="text" name=Material value="{{material.Id}}" class="in" readonly id="material_name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 topbox_insidebox_insideblocks">
        <select id="material_unit">
            <option value="{{material.Volume}}">m^3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 topbox_insidebox_insideblocks">
        <input type="text" name=Value value="{{material.Volume}}" class="in" readonly id="material_count">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-white topbox_button" id="addToCart" onclick="addDictToCookie('{{material.Id}}')"> Add</button>
</form>
```

I use variable of `django` for `<form>` tag. Now I want get value of input but defined var this function is `null`.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: i think you miss space try var name = $("#" +  id +" input[id = material_name]").val();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very small mistake in above code is to apply space after concatenating the `ID`

Incorrect code:

```
$("#" + id + "input[id = material_name]").val();
```

Correct Code:

```
$("#" + id + " input[id = material_name]").val();
```

Example :
Form id is `myForm`

If you will not apply space, jQuery will try to

Incorrect code:

```
$("#myForminput[id = material_name]").val();
```

In above example, `myForminput` id is not available in html, so it will always return `undefined`

Correct Code:

```
$("#myForm input[id = material_name]").val();
```

In below example I just remove `django` code so you can get clear idea:

```js
function addDictToCookie(id) {
    var name = $("#" + id + " input[id = material_name]").val();
    var unit = $("#" + id + " select[id = material_unit] :selected").text();
    var count = $("#" + id + " input[id = material_count]").val();
    var dict = { "name": name, "unit": unit, "count": count }
    
 console.log(dict) 
  
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
    <div class="col-sm-5 topbox_insidebox_insideblocks">
        <input type="text" name=Material value="Something" class="in" readonly id="material_name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 topbox_insidebox_insideblocks">
        <select id="material_unit">
            <option value="Some Value">Some Value</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 topbox_insidebox_insideblocks">
        <input type="text" name=Value value="123" class="in" readonly id="material_count">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-white topbox_button" id="addToCart" onclick="return addDictToCookie('myForm')"> Add</button>
</form>
```